# MySQL python normalization of tuple fails in query

Tags: python, mysql-python

When I try to pass a tuple to the `IN` argument of a `WHERE` clause, it gets double-quoted so my query fails.  For example, if I do this,

```
# Connect to DB
import MySQLdb
cnxn = MySQLdb.connect(connectString)
curs = cnxn.cursor()
# Setup query
accounts = ('Hyvaco','TLC')
truck_type = 'fullsize'
query_args = (truck_type, accounts)
sql ='SELECT * FROM archive.incoming WHERE LastCapacity=%s AND Account IN %s'
# Run query and print
curs.execute(sql, query_args)
print(curs._executed)
```

then I get zero rows back, and the query prints out as

```
SELECT * FROM archive.incoming WHERE LastCapacity='fullsize'
   AND Account IN ("'Hyvaco'", "'TLC'")
```

Switching `accounts` from a tuple to a list does not affect the result.  How should I be passing these arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create the accounts as a string and then do this:

```
accounts = "('Hyvaco','TLC')"

sql ='SELECT * FROM archive.incoming WHERE LastCapacity=%s AND Account IN '+ accounts
```

Comment: I did think of that and will do it if nothing more API-conformant comes up. Obviously in the general case it has issues with SQL injection.